# AIR_NOANDROIDFLAIR creates an install problem with air app

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

i was trying to get a rid of the "air." prefix for a soon to be published air app for android using the AIR_NOANDROIDFLAIR variable.
I used the

```
launchctl setenv AIR_NOANDROIDFLAIR true
```

terminal command for that since I am running MacOS

However if I try to install the apk on the android device I get

```
[INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_BAD_PACKAGE_NAME: Invalid manifest package: must have at least one '.' separator]
```

the manifest works fine with AIR_NOANDROIDFLAIR set to false.

Did something change or is there another issue hidden?

thanks!

Comment: What is your actual application ID? This is just a wild guess - let's say it has been **air.myapplication** because of the automatically prefixed **air.** it is now just **myapplication**. Try changing your application ID to something containing a dot e.g. **com.domain.myapplication**

Comment: Weee! That did the trick. Thanks a lot.
Would have never thought that this would be so restrictive.